# Functions Orthogonal to the decaying exponentials

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis

I am looking to find a set of functions that are orthogonal to the decaying exponentials. That is, is there a group of functions $f_n(x)$ such that the Integral over the domain of $f_n(x)e^{-nx}=0$
Thanks

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to find $\{f_n\}$ on $(0,+\infty)$ such that for all $1\le m\in\mathbb Z$ and for all $n$, $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,e^{-mx}\;dx=0$?

Comment: Exactly. Starting at 0 makes more sense as the exponential would diverge at negative infinity.

Comment: For any fixed $n$ and any domain $D\subseteq \Bbb R$, the space $\{f \in C^\infty(D) \mid \int_D f(x)e^{-nx}dx = 0\}$ is of infinite dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing variables by letting $x=e^t$, the question is essentially equivalent to asking for functions $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\cdot x^n\;dx = 0$ for all non-negative integers $n$. Taking Fourier transforms, for $f$ in the Schwartz space, this is equivalent to $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all non-negative integers $n$. It is easy, but not completely trivial, to make many Schwartz functions that vanish to infinite order at $0$, e.g., test functions supported away from $0$. The Fourier transforms of the latter are in the Paley-Wiener space, which is easy to characterize, but not non-trivially admitting explicit examples.

Comment: If $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$ then, using the taylor expansion, won't we have that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$? Basically, I'm trying to figure out whether a positive function can ever have an orthogonal basis, which would seem very unlikly to me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Yonahshmalo: No, not if $f$ is not analytic. Try $e^{-1/x^2}$. I have no idea what you mean by a function having an orthogonal basis.